# spectral sequence Ext(R/I,H^g(M)) => Ext^{p+q}(R/I,M)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I am reading papers of Local cohomology and came across some spectral sequences. I then started reading about spectral sequences from Rotman's book. I havent finished reading the chapters on spectrals sequences, but feel that I need to work with an example to use it more effectively. Here is one example which often appears in papers I am reading.

Suppose $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a Noetherian local ring and $I$ is an ideal of grade $g$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module. Then $Hom(R/I,H_I^g(M))\cong Ext^g(R/I,M)$ which can be readily seen from the spectral sequence $Ext^p(R/I,H_I^q(M))\Rightarrow Ext^{p+q}(R/I,M)$.

1. For the convergence, $Ext^p(R/I,H_I^q(M))\Rightarrow Ext^{p+q}(R/I,M)$, I was thinking of using the Cech complex for $H_I(M)$ and a free resolution for $R/I$, but I am not able to show the convergence to $Ext^{p+q}(R/I,M)$. How does one go about proving this convergence?
2. For the isomorphism $Hom(R/I,H_I^g(M))\cong Ext^g(R/I,M)$, is it because the above spectral sequences collapses on the axis that we are able to make this isomorphism?

Any help will be appreciated. Or a reference?

Comment: Conceptually, the local cohomology $R\Gamma_I\colon D(R)\to D_{I^\infty}(R)$ is a [right adjoint](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A6R) to the inclusion $D_{I^\infty}(R)\to D(R)$, and this adjunction is $R$-linear in the sense that $\operatorname{RHom}_R(M,R\Gamma_I(N))\cong\operatorname{RHom}_R(M,N)$ for $M\in D_{I^\infty}(R)$ and $N\in D(R)$. This holds in particular for $M=R/I$, and the spectral sequence is essentially associated to the composite of functors $\operatorname{RHom}_R(M,-)$ and $R\Gamma_I(-)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can understand that the spectral sequence is a composition of these functors. So why does it converge to $R \Hom_R(R/I,M)$. Is this   a known spectral sequence property?

Comment: Also, i know that $H_I^i(M)\cong\varinjlim \Ext^i(R/I^n,M)$ and then use the change of rings of spectral sequences?

Comment: You do not need any formula for the local cohomology (the formula you wrote needs the Noetherian assumption which could be eliminated). It holds for general composite functors. Compare with section 1.4 of https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gregoric/GSS.pdf

Comment: Does the isomorphism follow from the convergence of the spectral sequence? It seems to me from your earlier argument, the isomorphism follows independent of the spectral sequence. is that correct?

Comment: It depends on how you define local cohomology. The general local cohomology (without Noetherian assumption, but assuming that the ideal is of finite type) is defined in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0952 which formally leads to the adjunction that I wrote. To compare with some "classical" definitions for Noetherian rings, look at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BJD